# Обойти визуальное дерево в WPF из нескольких потоков

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

Имеется приложение с весьма большим визуальным деревом. Для некоторых задач я реализовал механизм, который позволяет запомнить всё визульное дерево в набор xml-файлов.

Xотелось бы ускорить этот механизм. Сейчас он работает для независимых частей интерфейса, поэтому я решил вынести запись каждой интерфейсной части в xml-файл в отдельный поток.

Проблема заключается в обходе визуального дерева не из UI-потока. WPF не позволяет обратиться стороннему потоку к элементу, которым он не владаеет (**InvalidOperationException**).

В таких ситуациях я как правило пользуюсь *Dispatcher.Invoke* или *Dispatcher.BeginInvoke*. В случае с этой задачей это не имеет смысла, потому что делегируя выполнение через эти методы всё будет выполнятся всё равно в одном (интерейсном) потоке, и я не получу никакого прироста производительности.

**Вопрос**

Возможно ли каким-нибудь способом обойти визуальное дерево из нескольких потоков сразу? Возможно кто-то сталкивался с такой задачей? Буду благодарен за любые предложения и помощь.

**UPD:**

Основное время занимает получения списка свойств у DependencyObject, код получения списка свойств:

private static List GetDependencyProperties(DependencyObject obj)

```
{
        List<DependencyProperty> result = new List<DependencyProperty>();

        PropertyDescriptorCollection attCollect = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj,
            new Attribute[] { new PropertyFilterAttribute(PropertyFilterOptions.All) });

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor pd in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj,
            new Attribute[] { new PropertyFilterAttribute(PropertyFilterOptions.All) }))
        {
            DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd =
                DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(pd);

            if (dpd != null && 
                _filter.IsValidProperty(dpd.DependencyProperty.Name, obj.GetType().Name, dpd.DependencyProperty.OwnerType.Name))
            {
                result.Add(dpd.DependencyProperty);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

_filter - это обертка над Dictionary, в котором хранится список исключаемых свойств.

Comment: Нет, это невозможно, WPF однопоточный. Мне кажется, вы подходите к задаче неправильно. Фоновая работа должна быть задачей модели, а не представления. Вы используете MVVM? Если да, выгрузите работу в модель, посылайте обновления в VM, и пусть View подхватывает их через привязки.

Comment: Это не задача для MVVM. Мне нужно обойти визуальное дерево и получить набор xml-файлов максимально быстро. Нужно это для проверки в автоматических тестах приложения. Основная работа - это взять список всех DependencyProperty с каждого UIElementa и набить ими атрибуты XML-узла. Да, похоже что и правда не существует средств сделать это в многопоточном режиме...

Comment: Если это и вправду задача UI-уровня, то ответ, судя по всему, отрицательный. Впрочем, для автоматизированных тестов скорость не должна быть по сути критичной.

Comment: Но вы можете хотя бы отделить запись в файл в фоновый поток. В главном потоке можно просто создать нужное объектное дерево, а его обработку/запись унести в фон. Это может и не ускорить процесс, т. к. объём записываемой информации тот же. Ускорение будет только если у вас по дороге есть параллелизируемая обработка дерева.

Comment: С другой стороны, что-то вы делаете не так. Визуальное дерево не может быть таким уж огромным, ведь его как-то может обработать WPF? Может быть, ваш метод обхода сам по себе медленный, и может быть ускорен? Например, может быть вы пользуетесь рефлексией и не кешируете результаты. Покажите ваш код.

Comment: Обхожу дерево в глубину. Дерево действительно большое (несколько десятков тысяч UIElement'ов),его обход "вхолостую" занимает всего 1мс (видимо в MS очень постарались :)). Свойства с UIElement'ов я беру не через рефлексию, а с помощью TypeDescriptor.GetProperties [ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx). Как написано на msdn этот механизм отличен от рефлексии. Хотя и не сказано быстрее это работает или медленнее. Могу прислать код получения списка проперти, если вы ещё заинтересованы.

Comment: Давайте код, попробую поиграться. Может быть, правильнее будет для каждого типа закешировать имена свойств?

Comment: @VladD Добавил код получения свойств

Comment: Я попробовал закешировать список свойств по типу, ускорение сразу в раз 50, а то и больше. Поэкспериментирую ещё.

Comment: @Druus: Поскольку вы не возвращаетесь к обсуждению, вот вам склад найденных ссылок: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4794071/276994, http://stackoverflow.com/q/27603939/276994, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/580234cb-e870-4af1-9a91-3e3ba118c89c/getting-list-of-all-dependencyattached-properties-of-an-object?forum=wpf